# Rail Fence Cipher cryptanalytic attacks

Tags: encryption

Is it true that the most effective real world attack on the Rail Fence cipher is still to this day brute force even after hundreds of years?  Does this mean that the cipher isn't cryptographically broken even though it can be brute forced?

Comment: Define "isn't cryptographically broken" in the context when it can be brute-forced in almost zero time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question appears to be off-topic because it is about security or cryptography and doesn't include a programming problem.